# Google Authentication resulting in origin_mismatch error.

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I have done code for getting list of google analytics accounts
and its works fine with a static clientid

I have used this tutorial:  [Hello Analytics API: JavaScript quickstart for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js)

The problem is:

I want this functionality for all users means my users logged in from their Google Accounts and they all can see their Google Analytics accounts list.

However I am seeing an error:  "origin_mismatch"

I want this without set origin because I can not set origin for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Origin mismatch is normally caused by the Javascript origins incorect in the project on [google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard). Check and make sure that the Javascript origins match the domain from which your requests are coming and to which you are returning the user after login in.

[Creating a Google API Console project and client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project)

> In the Authorized JavaScript origins field, enter the origin for your
>   app. You can enter multiple origins to allow for your app to run on
>   different protocols, domains, or subdomains. You cannot use wildcards.
>   In the example below, the second URL could be a production URL.
>   http://localhost:8080
>  https://myproductionurl.example.com

**Answer**: If you are using JavaScript you need to set the origin for the server that you are returning authentication to.  There is no way around this.  Just add your server and your users will be able to access it.  There is no need to set it for each user.  The origin is to your server hosting the script.